Azure pipeline exits with this error ##[error]Bash exited with code '5'. for python repo
I've created an azure pipeline by following the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops#3-customize-your-pipeline
I've used same script mentioned in the official link as below
  - script: |
      pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
      pytest
    displayName: 'pytest'

enter image description here
After running my python script, building & publishing artifacts, the pipeline is failing at this step with the below error.
*Error:*
**
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.12.3, pytest-8.2.2, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: /home/vsts/work/1/s
plugins: anyio-4.4.0, azurepipelines-1.0.5, nunit-1.0.7
collected 0 items
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
No Result Found to Publish '/home/vsts/work/1/s/test-output.xml'.
Skipping uploading of coverage data.

-------- generated Nunit xml file: /home/vsts/work/1/s/test-output.xml ---------
============================ no tests ran in 0.01s =============================

##[error]Bash exited with code '5'.
Async Command Start: Publish test results
Async Command End: Publish test results
Finishing: pytest**

enter image description here
Will you please help me with the fix?
  - script: |
      pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
      pytest
    displayName: 'pytest'


Hi Nintendo, Welcome to SO. May I know if you were also testing with the same code of the sample repo from the document? Does the same YAML pipeline work with the code in that repo?

Please copy and paste the code and error message into your question rather than posting screenshots.

Hi @Nintendo, May I know the latest status of the issue and if the answer below helps resolve your issue in this post? Thx.

My pipeline running pytest with the sample code in the repo shared in the document was working as expected.

I could only reproduce the issue when I removed test*.py from my repo.


Please be advised to double check this in your source code.
